# QT 5.5 Program crashes when using QApplication::activeWindow->winId() in other window

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to realize the function that takes a screenshot when the global hot key was activated. And I applied [this](https://github.com/hellogdut/MyGlobalShortcut) into my project so I can easily create a global hot key.

To use the screen->grabWindow(), I have to get the WinID of the active window. So I found the QApplication::activeWindow()->winId() and then used it.

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QPixmap screenShot = screen->grabWindow(QApplication::activeWindow()->winId(), 0, 0, -1,-1);
```

However, things are going to the wrong way. When I press the hot key in other windows, the program just crashes with "untitled2.exe has stopped working".(sorry for not being able to put on an image[http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/bcbe8e8cgw1euarn4mcb6j20vt09ojtk.jpg ])

And I found that the same situation happens even when I simply qDebug() it. Not only winId(), but also windowTitle(), setWindowTitle() and so on.

```
qDebug() << QApplication::activeWindow()->winId();
```

Can anyone help me work it out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where exactly does the crash occur? Try to attach a debugger and tell us what is says.

Comment: @LukasBoersma The debugger said that "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. Signal SIGSEGV name: Signal Segmentation meaningfault:"

Comment: That basically just says that a crash happened. Which debugger are you using? Can you get the exact location in your source or the Qt sources where the crash occurs?

Comment: @LukasBoersma I think it's where I use "QApplication::activeWindow()->winId()". Because whenever I use it, it crashes.

Comment: Your debugger should be able to tell you where exactly in the Qt sources the crash happens and what the internal state of the window widget is. Without that information, it will be hard to help you, because calling winId() is perfectly valid and should not cause a crash. Try installing QtCreator and debugging your program with it if you are not doing that already. The only thing I could guess without any further information is that QApplication::activeWindow() could be null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It crashes because `QApplication::activeWindow()` returns null. It will do so if no application window has the focus (this is verbatim from the documentation). No application window having focus means that none of *your* application windows have focus.

So, this approach simply won't work for what you're attempting to do. You need to use platform-specific ways of doing it.